# Pass a matrix to functions from different module (Python)

Tags: python, function, matrix, module, arguments

I'm working on my Computer Graphics homework. Since we're allowed to choose the PL we want, I decided this would be a good occasion to learn some Python, but I ran into some trouble, eventually.

In one module I have some functions like this:

```
def function1 (a, b, matrix):
   ...
   function2 (matrix)

def function2(matrix):
   ...
   function3(x,y,matrix):

def function3(x,y,matrix):
   ...
   matrix[x][y] = something
```

Now, from a different module, I call function1. It should then call `function2` passing it the matrix, which should in turn call `function3` passing it the matrix. However, I get a list assignment index out of range when attempting to access `matrix[x][y`.

If I try to call them on a matrix from the same module, it will work, so I thought that the functions might not realize they are receiving a matrix. I changed the function definitions to something like

```
function2(matrix = [[]])
```

but I still get the same error. I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in code that you yada-yada'd over rather than in the code you showed us. Where does `function2` get those `x` and `y` values to pass to `function3`? Those are presumably out of range, but from "..." I can't guess _why_ they're out of range, or what they should be instead.

Comment: This should work fine, so there is probably an error in your actual code. Think about adding an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is everything fine Python in this case, the problem is in `x,y` , try printing them and analyse by yourself where is it getting `IndexError`

Comment: I checked them, they are not out of range. They are pixels being colored in an image matrix. The matrix itself is defined in the 2nd module, and I've made sure nothing that tries to access it is out of range. I can't really add an MCVE since it would be a lot of code, no matter what. I'll try though.

Comment: If they're not out of range, you won't get this error. So you checked wrong. And if you don't give us code that we can check, nobody can tell you any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, you were right.

There was this one pixel in a 500x500, which was actually at matrix[249][500].
When I made the checks, I checked if they're <=500 instead of <500, don't know why.

Thanks, I was pretty sure I was screwing something else up, especially after I added my (faulty) tests, since this is my first time writing python.